# Finding initial conditions for which solutions to IVP are periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

I have an initial value problem  $\mathbf x'=A\mathbf x$ 
 $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &0  &0 \\ 
3& -1 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &-2 \\ 
0 &0  &2  &0
\end{pmatrix}$$

My initial condition is  $\mathbf x (0) = \mathbf x_0$.
I need to use the matrix exponential to "determine all initial vectors $\mathbf x_0$  for which the solutions are periodic".

I've got my Eigenvalues as $2, -2, 2i, -2i$.

My understanding is that eigenvectors that span the center subspace (who have corresponding eigenvalues with real part 0) are periodic - correct? Do I only need to solve for the eigenvectors whose eigenvalues have real part being 0? If so, what happens after I get those?  I'm unsure how to be approaching this.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the matrix $A$ has block form 
$$\begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix}$$
This implies that $(x_1,x_2)$ is driven by $2\times 2$ matrix $B$, while $(x_3,x_4)$ is driven by matrix $C$; there is no interaction between these processes.

Since the eigenvalues of $C$ are $\pm 2i$, all its orbits are periodic. That is, $(x_3,x_4)$ are periodic no matter what the initial condition.

Since the eigenvalues of $A$ have nonzero real part, none of  its orbits are periodic... except the trivial, zero solution, which is periodic to every period.

Hence, the conclusion: solution is periodic if and only if the starting point has the first two coordinates zero.

Using the matrix exponential isn't really necessary. But if you want to: 
$$
e^{tA} = \begin{pmatrix} e^{tB} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{tC} \end{pmatrix}$$ where $e^{tC}$ is sometimes the identity, but $e^{tB}$ never is, except at $t=0$.